# Entity relationship model diagram

Tags: sql

I need to design an entity relationship diagram for a movie database with the following requirements..

1. Each movie is identified by its title, year of release and length in minutes and can have 0 or more languages
2. Production companies are identified by name. They have an address and each production company can produce one or more movies
3. Actors are identified by name, date of birth and can act in one or more movies - and each has a role in movies
4. Directors are identified by name and date of birth, so each director can direct one or more movies, and each movie can be directed by one or more directors
5. Each movie belongs to any one category like horror, action, drama etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your actual problem?

Comment: If you are new to SQL, try MySQL workbench, it can help you create ER diagrams.